# Cumm count on additional two columns based on a few conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling with pandas where by condition especially in a group by

I am having following dataframe

```
   data = {'script':['a','a','a','b','b'],
           'call_put':['C', 'P', 'P','C', 'P'],
           'strike':[280,260,275,280,285],
           'premium':[10,20,35,38,50]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['t']=df['premium'].cumsum()
    df

   script  call_put  strike  premium    t
0   a        C        280     10       10
1   a        P        260     20       30
2   a        P        275     35       65
3   b        C        280     38       103
4   b        P        285     50       153
```

I want two additional columns having running count based on script and call_put and premium > 0 expected output

```
             k1  k2
a   c  10   1   1               call_put is "C" so first value should be 1, k2 column should be also one as call_put "P" is 0 
a   p  30   1   1               for call_put value is P so second column count 1
a   P  65   1   2               as value is "P", so increase cumm count by 1
b   C  103  1   1               script value changed, "C" is 1 and "P" = 0 so 1
b   P  153  1   1               "C" = 1 and "P" = 1
```

can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: what's ```k1``` though, is it supposed to be ```1``` everywhere ?

Comment: for ```k2``` as far as I understood you - something like that should do the trick: ```df.loc[df["premium"]>0].groupby(["script", "call_put"]).cumcount()+1```

Comment: K1 and K2 are column counts based on script, call_put and amt or premium > 0

Comment: I want to create two different columns having cumm count  based on a condition, your query is not giving expected output

Comment: df['x']=df.loc[df["premium"]>0].groupby(["script", "call_put"]).cumcount()+1

Comment: What is the logic for column K1? And will the `call_put` for a script always start with C?

Comment: df["k1"] = (df["call_put"]=="C").cumsum()
df["k2"] = (df["call_put"]=="P").cumsum()
df
group by script and where premium/amt > 0, how to do this ? basically wants to create two columns in a dataframe group by script, call_put where premium > 0

Comment: logic for column k1 is it should give cumm count based on script and call_put = "C" and premium > 0

Comment: do you mean value of k1 should give count of unique combination of script and call_put where premium > 0?
why does value of k2 changed from 2 to 1 on 4th row?

Comment: can you explain what should be the value of k1 for any row in single sentence. Your condition is so confusing

Comment: k1 = cumm count on unique combination of script, call_put where call_put = "C" and premium > 0

Comment: k2 = cumm count on unique combination of script, call_put where call_put = "P" and premium > 0 value of k2 change 1 because script value changed from a to b

Comment: What should happen if `premium < 0`? With what do you want the column be filled?

Comment: we can put value 0 if premium < 0 for both k1 and k2 columns

Comment: And also, what should happen in `k1` where `call_put` is not `'C'`?

Comment: call_put value will be always "C" or "P", if other than this again for K1 and K2 columns we can put value 0

Comment: Yes, but I mean: in `k1` you want to count the combinations with `call_put == 'C'`. Hovewer some rows will have `'P'`. What numbers should appear in those rows? 0 again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your explanation, this what you need.

```
df['k1'] = df.loc[df["premium"]>0].groupby(["script"])['call_put'].apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(x=='C'))
df['k2'] = df.loc[df["premium"]>0].groupby(["script"])['call_put'].apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(x=='P'))
```

**Output**

```
script  call_put    strike  premium   t     k1  k2
a         C          280      10     10     1   0
a         P          260      20     30     1   1
a         P          275      35     65     1   2
b         C          280      38     103    1   0
b         P          285      50     153    1   1
```

Comment: good. If you need 1's instead of 0`s when the `cumsum()` is 0 (to match what you have put in the question), then just add `.replace(0,1)` at the end of each line.

Comment: @Parag check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

may be you need four columns to represent the cumsum as there will be 4 different combinations of script and call_put. Following code do as per you told. The count start from zero here

```py
data = {'script':['a','a','a','b','b'],
        'call_put':['C', 'P', 'P','C', 'P'],
         'strike':[280,260,275,280,285],
         'premium':[10,20,35,38,50]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['t']=df['premium'].cumsum()

## column cond_col will have unique combination of script, call_put and premium >0
df["cond_col"] = df["script"] + "-" + df["call_put"] + "-" + (df["premium"]>0).astype(np.str)


## and new columns for each unique combination
for col in np.unique(df["cond_col"]):
    df[col] = df["cond_col"]==col

## do cumsum in each unique combination column
for col in np.unique(df["cond_col"]):
    df[col] = df[col].cumsum()

## may be the solution you want is upto here

## if you want to combine the columns then you can do following
df["k1"] = df["a-C-True"].where(df["cond_col"]=="a-C-True", df["b-C-True"])
df["k2"] = df["a-P-True"].where(df["cond_col"]=="a-P-True", df["b-P-True"])
df
```

**Output**

```
script  call_put    strike  premium t   cond_col    a-C-True    a-P-True    b-C-True    b-P-True    k1  k2
0   a   C   280 10  10  a-C-True    1   0   0   0   1   0
1   a   P   260 20  30  a-P-True    1   1   0   0   0   1
2   a   P   275 35  65  a-P-True    1   2   0   0   0   2
3   b   C   280 38  103 b-C-True    1   2   1   0   1   0
4   b   P   285 50  153 b-P-True    1   2   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Dev, thanks for your help and time, but first answer i think more elegant and easy